# Print some data before sending email (Contact form 7)

Tags: wordpress, forms, pdf, printing, contact-form-7

I use in a CMS wordpress website form (Contact Form 7) for recording the patients. The need arose to after clicking the button to sign in before sending email has printed some coupon with the user-entered data in a pre-prepared template.

How to implement it? Please help.

screen http://pastenow.ru/2EQF9

Comment: have you tried firing a sequence of events (asynchronously or not) at the click of the button?

Comment: Yet, as I do not understand the process of generating a "coupon". That is, taking user input from forms and output them to the prepared template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i get from your question is 
So before sending mail, you need to show which data is sending. for this, you can use the hook

```
    add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body' );

  function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body($contact_form){

   $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        print_r($posted_data)
    }

}
```

Comment: There after a successful form submission (that is, if they are completed) that besides sending mail, the user needs to bring the page where they will introduced some of them data to enable them to print.

Comment: you get data before send a mail and by using mpdf https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf you can create dynamic one can attach this in user mail